# Create VirtualHost with DocumentRoot in another server

Tags: apache, centos7, virtualhost, firewall, hosts

I have two server VM with centos 7. With IP public `103.x.x.78` and domain `one.example.go.id`
This IP local is `192.168.10.200` (Server A).

I created another one VM with IP local `192.168.10.103` (Server B). With planned to pointing my other domain `two.example.go.id`

This my configuration:

```
one.example.go.id pointing to 103.x.x.78
```

I have create VirtualHost with DocumentRoot `/var/www/html` and work.

Then

```
two.example.go.id pointing to 103.x.x.78
```

I try to open this domain worked. Open webpage.

Create /etc/hosts at Server A:

```
192.168.10.103 two.example.go.id
```

And create VirtualHost at Server B

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.two.example.go.id
    ServerAlias two.example.go.id
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.two.example.go.id
    ServerAlias two.example.go.id
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

I have access IP 192.168.10.103 or two.example.go.id in server A it load perfectly. But when I access with two.example.go.id in other device (Internet), it doesn't work. This site can't be reached.

Is there a step I missed?

*This my first question with poor english. CMIIW

Comment: Did you also add a `/etc/hosts` to the Server B? Because `/etc/hosts` works only on the device you have added it on. For example, if you add a `/etc/hosts` directive in Server A, it will only work for Server A. You have to add the same for Server B also.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also add a `/etc/hosts` to the Server B? Because `/etc/hosts` works only on the device you have added it on. For example, if you add a `/etc/hosts` directive in Server A, it will only work for Server A. You have to add the same for Server B also.

Or, if you don't want to use /etc/hosts because of this, then you can setup a DNS server of your own in your local network.